# How to obtain the 2D decision boundaries of a convolutional neural network for image classification?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, dimensionality-reduction

In the paper [Robust Learning with Jacobian Regularization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.02729) the authors use a method to visualize the decision boundary of a convolutional neural network for image classification. More specifically, in Figure 1 they explain

> Cross sections of decision cells in the input space. To make these
> cross sections for LeNet’ models trained on the MNIST dataset, a test
> sample (black dot) and a two-dimensional hyperplane ⊂ R 784 passing
> through it are randomly chosen. Different colors indicate the
> different classes predicted by these models, transparency and contours
> are set by maximum of the softmax values, and the circle around the
> test sample signifies distance to the closest decision boundary in the
> plane.

I did not understand how those cross sections were obtained. I understand that in the case of a 2D input I just have to take a sample, produce some perturbations around that sample and classify them. But in the case of a 28x28 image, how can I obtain a 2D sample and perturbate it?